# DevExtreme - dxDatagrid - push insert into 0 index not working as expected

Tags: angular, devextreme-angular, dx-data-grid

basically trying to insert row into dxDataGrid component using store.push:

```js
store.push([
  {
    type: "insert",
    data: data,
    key: data.id,
    index: 0
  }
]);
```

And the issue is - inserted row immediately goes to the bottom. Same issue with CustomStore.

Sandbox here (use Test button): https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-array-devextreme-data-grid-forked-wy2cqy?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:1036-1179The only work around I have is using ArrayStore and modifying array directly, and using dataSource.reload() after that. But we can't always use ArrayStore and it also has it's downsides.

It totally should work according the docs ("To display the new data item first, set the index to 0"): https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/ArrayStore/Methods/#pushchanges